# Fine control of date X-axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an R-script that downloads covid testing data and does some manipulation to come up with weekly totals for the percent of the population tested in selected states and the rate of positive tests, aggregated by week.  The following R-script uses a big dput in place of downloading and manipulating the data for purposes of reproducibility

```
stateWeekly <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1586044800, 1586649600, 1587254400, 
1587859200, 1588464000, 1589068800, 1589673600, 1586044800, 1586649600, 
1587254400, 1587859200, 1588464000, 1589068800, 1589673600, 1586044800, 
1586649600, 1587254400, 1587859200, 1588464000, 1589068800, 1589673600, 
1586044800, 1586649600, 1587254400, 1587859200, 1588464000, 1589068800, 
1589673600, 1586044800, 1586649600, 1587254400, 1587859200, 1588464000, 
1589068800, 1589673600, 1586044800, 1586649600, 1587254400, 1587859200, 
1588464000, 1589068800, 1589673600, 1586044800, 1586649600, 1587254400, 
1587859200, 1588464000, 1589068800, 1589673600, 1586044800, 1586649600, 
1587254400, 1587859200, 1588464000, 1589068800, 1589673600, 1586044800, 
1586649600, 1587254400, 1587859200, 1588464000, 1589068800, 1589673600
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), positiveIncrease = c(306L, 
631L, 624L, 862L, 1072L, 1046L, 1079L, 2096L, 1675L, 1762L, 2597L, 
3510L, 1808L, 2403L, 7730L, 8356L, 8539L, 11831L, 11452L, 13064L, 
12159L, 3996L, 5805L, 5849L, 5100L, 5201L, 4839L, 4260L, 823L, 
718L, 629L, 654L, 719L, 617L, 721L, 886L, 698L, 766L, 1054L, 
1052L, 1076L, 987L, 2390L, 2561L, 4998L, 4361L, 3951L, 4167L, 
3842L, 7905L, 7204L, 6641L, 5532L, 4550L, 4518L, 4992L, 7546L, 
12979L, 14439L, 15118L, 13149L, 9706L, 8217L), totalTestResultsIncrease = c(5822L, 
11864L, 7940L, 17103L, 21209L, 22109L, 31531L, 24726L, 25377L, 
26421L, 51123L, 56386L, 57262L, 63411L, 90276L, 73795L, 90572L, 
245184L, 189667L, 239913L, 279579L, 15268L, 26621L, 25480L, 43290L, 
51873L, 68451L, 107628L, 1019L, 20107L, 12805L, 17579L, 10632L, 
32192L, 27504L, 16899L, 13342L, 19321L, 32147L, 26400L, 24408L, 
24242L, 23091L, 19487L, 24056L, 29087L, 33780L, 54696L, 59600L, 
70088L, 69349L, 73326L, 88534L, 83576L, 110759L, 112844L, 32877L, 
44877L, 52271L, 66985L, 78546L, 73743L, 72437L), posRate = c(5.25592579869461, 
5.3186109238031, 7.85894206549118, 5.04005145296147, 5.05445801310764, 
4.73110497987245, 3.42202911420507, 8.47690689961983, 6.60046498798124, 
6.66893758752507, 5.07990532636974, 6.22494945553861, 3.15741678600119, 
3.78956332497516, 8.56263015640923, 11.3232603834948, 9.42785849931546, 
4.82535565126599, 6.03795072416393, 5.44530725721407, 4.34903909091885, 
26.1723866911187, 21.8060929341497, 22.9552590266876, 11.7810117810118, 
10.0264106567964, 7.0692904413376, 3.95807782361467, 80.765456329735, 
3.5708957079624, 4.91214369386958, 3.72034814267023, 6.76260346124906, 
1.91662524850895, 2.62143688190809, 5.24291378188058, 5.23159946035077, 
3.96459810568811, 3.27868852459016, 3.98484848484848, 4.40839069157653, 
4.07144625030938, 10.3503529513663, 13.1420947298199, 20.7765214499501, 
14.9929521779489, 11.696269982238, 7.61847301448003, 6.44630872483221, 
11.2786782330784, 10.3880373184905, 9.05681477238633, 6.24844692434545, 
5.44414664496985, 4.07912675267924, 4.42380631668498, 22.9522158347781, 
28.9212737036789, 27.6233475540931, 22.5692319175935, 16.740508746467, 
13.1619272337713, 11.3436503444372), dailyTest = c(0.138828678924223, 
0.282903374571794, 0.189333512651723, 0.407830109179146, 0.505739857661259, 
0.527200835165862, 0.751873424108499, 0.181032142393795, 0.185798458202998, 
0.193442135168909, 0.374298560850844, 0.412831771455816, 0.419245431438707, 
0.464265517323178, 0.114238067546845, 0.0933824958418563, 0.114612635183801, 
0.310263484795578, 0.240010540535773, 0.303593396909103, 0.353787991123658, 
0.0719006862588031, 0.125364695369112, 0.11999145178637, 0.203863027779905, 
0.244282440287064, 0.32235223179862, 0.506846152781141, 0.0128760104635591, 
0.254070600972309, 0.161803055923331, 0.222126975406188, 0.134345184738529, 
0.406775788854657, 0.347538559165584, 0.263556166362753, 0.208081328576357, 
0.30132958697525, 0.501363399021447, 0.411733403868672, 0.380666247031309, 
0.378077317294862, 0.0987715050773798, 0.0833554336946386, 0.102899282237298, 
0.124419330829576, 0.144493588043562, 0.233961553926307, 0.254938361379405, 
0.163164303576303, 0.161443917485348, 0.170702341685253, 0.206106444082074, 
0.194564259726246, 0.257846066370959, 0.262699929699297, 0.238498263983345, 
0.325549368640101, 0.379187357626105, 0.48592652045273, 0.569793005530792, 
0.534950800891926, 0.525476739001782), state = c("NM 3.28%", 
"NM 3.28%", "NM 3.28%", "NM 3.28%", "NM 3.28%", "NM 3.28%", "NM 3.28%", 
"TN 2.53%", "TN 2.53%", "TN 2.53%", "TN 2.53%", "TN 2.53%", "TN 2.53%", 
"TN 2.53%", "CA 1.69%", "CA 1.69%", "CA 1.69%", "CA 1.69%", "CA 1.69%", 
"CA 1.69%", "CA 1.69%", "GA 1.78%", "GA 1.78%", "GA 1.78%", "GA 1.78%", 
"GA 1.78%", "GA 1.78%", "GA 1.78%", "OK 1.76%", "OK 1.76%", "OK 1.76%", 
"OK 1.76%", "OK 1.76%", "OK 1.76%", "OK 1.76%", "UT 2.71%", "UT 2.71%", 
"UT 2.71%", "UT 2.71%", "UT 2.71%", "UT 2.71%", "UT 2.71%", "OH 1.19%", 
"OH 1.19%", "OH 1.19%", "OH 1.19%", "OH 1.19%", "OH 1.19%", "OH 1.19%", 
"FL 1.67%", "FL 1.67%", "FL 1.67%", "FL 1.67%", "FL 1.67%", "FL 1.67%", 
"FL 1.67%", "MA 3.46%", "MA 3.46%", "MA 3.46%", "MA 3.46%", "MA 3.46%", 
"MA 3.46%", "MA 3.46%")), row.names = c(NA, -63L), class = "data.frame")

g <- stateWeekly %>% ggplot(aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_col(aes(y=100*dailyTest), size=0.75, color="darkblue", fill="white") +
  geom_line(aes(y=posRate), size = 0.75, color="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Test Positivity Rate", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, name="Percent of Pop Tested")) +
  labs(x = "Week Ending",
       title = "COVID-19 Testing",
       subtitle = paste("Data as of", format(max(stateWeekly$Date), "%A, %B %e, %y")),
       caption = "HQ AFMC/A9A \n Data: The COVID Tracking Project (https://covidtracking.com)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1), face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = rel(0.7)),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = rel(1)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color='red'),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color="blue"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color="blue")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,75)) +
  facet_wrap(~ state)

print(g)
```

which produces this chart

[image]

Hopefully it's clear that the line plot is the test positivity rate and the columns are the percent of the population tested.

How can I align the dates on the X-axis with the centers of the corresponding columns?  You'll notice that right now they seem somewhat irregular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a nice plot! Here is a solution. 
1) Use `as.Date()` to tell R that this column contains dates.
2) Use the `scale_x_date()` function to fin-tune the x axis. 
3) Adjust the x axis labels with `axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1))` to avoid overlapping.

Code:

```
stateWeekly %>% ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(Date))) +
  geom_col(aes(y=100*dailyTest), size=0.75, color="darkblue", fill="white") +
  geom_line(aes(y=posRate), size = 0.75, color="red") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Test Positivity Rate", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, name="Percent of Pop Tested")) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 week') +
  labs(x = "Week Ending",
       title = "COVID-19 Testing",
       subtitle = paste("Data as of", format(max(stateWeekly$Date), "%A, %B %e, %y")),
       caption = "HQ AFMC/A9A \n Data: The COVID Tracking Project (https://covidtracking.com)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1), face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = rel(0.7)),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = rel(1)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color='red'),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="red"),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color="blue"),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(color="blue"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust = 1)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,75)) +
  facet_wrap(~ state)
```

[image: covid]

Comment: Thanks!  I'm relatively new to R still.  Interesting that I created the Date column by doing `mutate(Date = as.Date(as.character(date), format="%Y%m%d"))` from the original data's date which was just recognized as numeric, but I still need to tell ggplot that Date is as.Date!

Comment: How can I format the X-axis date labels to drop the year?

Comment: disregard! Found `date_labels = "%b %d"`